# Enabling hibernate in 12.04 stops reboot and shutdown

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, reboot

I enabled hibernate by setting the policy in `/var/lib/.../10-vendor.d`.

Once I set this field, I was able to hibernate jolly well again, but then the reboot and shutdown went to fast reboot mode and started showing the login screen bypassing the grub loading.

I don't have `kexec-tools` installed and unable to figure out how to get rid of the fast reboot.